# Automatic clear Desktop AD User

Tags: windows, server, desktop

I've an AD domain with AD Users. I'd like to clear their desktop at 10 PM.
The process can clear the folder and file in their desktop.Not program icons...
IT's possible to create a script for do this for all Users?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best way is to write a batch script and deploy this script via Group policy

In Group Policy management:   Computer Configuration, Policies and click Scripts.
import the following script as: "deletedesktop.bat"

something like:

```
FOR /D %%p IN ("%USERPROFILE%\desktop\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

Comment: Maybe you ad something to copy the stuff away to a backup location. just in case someone does miss something, and needs to be restore
xcopy will do the job